# how to set alias for fields on AdonisJS ORM?

Tags: adonis.js

I'm trying to get state, city and slaughter from this query. I've tried this and it only returns 1 of them as 'name' which is name of each place in 'places' table. how can I get alias for them? I didn't find anything on documents.

```
     const bargiris = await Database
    .table('bargiris')
    .innerJoin('users', 'bargiris.nazer_id', 'users.id')
    .innerJoin('companies', 'bargiris.sherkat_id', 'companies.id')
    .innerJoin('sifs', 'bargiris.sif_code', 'sifs.sif_id')
    .innerJoin('places', function() {
      this.on('sifs.state_id', 'places.id')
        .orOn('sifs.city_id', 'places.id')
        .orOn('sifs.slaughter_id', 'places.id')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the **select()** method and pass the field names with an alias

```
const bargiris = await Database
    .table('bargiris')
    .innerJoin('users', 'bargiris.nazer_id', 'users.id')
    .innerJoin('companies', 'bargiris.sherkat_id', 'companies.id')
    .innerJoin('sifs', 'bargiris.sif_code', 'sifs.sif_id')
    .innerJoin('places', function() {
        this.on('sifs.state_id', 'places.id')
        .orOn('sifs.city_id', 'places.id')
        .orOn('sifs.slaughter_id', 'places.id')
    })
   .select('state.name as state', 'city.name as city')
```

Comment: there is no state or city, all of them are in places table. nvm I solved it with a mysql view.